# Problem with installing Pomegranate in my code

Tags: python, bash, pip, pomegranate

Hey guys so for my coding class I want to test out one of the practice examples using probability. The file imports Pomegranate but when I try to install Pomegranate it keeps giving me this error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5Kuw.png)

Comment: Please post codes, console logs, and error messages as **text**. That would make it easier for people to copy and search for the problem. Also, you only showed the first parts of the error message ("*Command errored out with exit code status 1*"), which isn't really helpful. Try reading through the entire logs to find other lines with `Error`'s or "failed" messages.

Comment: This may be a bug report (off-topic here) rather than a programming question. As a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it by doing a pip install cython first, before installing Pomegranate.

Alternatively,

On Windows machines you may need to download a C++ compiler if you wish to build from source yourself. For Python 2 this minimal version of Visual Studio 2008 works well:   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266

For Python 3 this version of the Visual Studio build tools has been reported to work.
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126